# Aggregations in VisualStudio 2019 // SSAS

Tags: ssas, aggregation, sql-server-data-tools

We have VS 2019 for SSAS development (with installed SSDT).
I would like to create aggregations for measures in order to increase query performance (cube with tabular model).
Could you tell, please, where the window "Aggregation" is located in VS?

P.S. on the screen you can see a snapshot from the video on youtube where i highlighted the ribbon (and button) i am searching for.

[image: screen]

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshot, it looks like, You are looking into a video on SSAS (multi dimensional). It is having aggregations. For SSAS (Tabular), there are no custom aggregations.

You can see the difference between SSAS (multidimensional) Vs SSAS (Tabular) [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/comparing-tabular-and-multidimensional-solutions-ssas?view=sql-analysis-services-2022)

| Feature | Multidimensional | Tabular |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Aggregations | Yes | No |